# Will the image of a pinhole camera be shifted if the light source is shifted as well?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, camera

If the angle of incidence ray is = to the angle of reflection. Then if the light source is shifted won't the image change too?[image]

Comment: you mean, the sun?

Comment: @philip_0008  yep

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. the tree is not a mirror, so light just diffuses to all directions once light is reflected from it.

Comment: PS. Yes, it might change in color.

Comment: why colour? Isnt it like the position? Sorry i dont really get it

Comment: Look at the green arrow from the top of the tree, toward the pinhole, then to the back screen. it won't change its position as long as you won't move the tree or the camera (even if you move the sun).

Comment: so just to confirm. If the black arrows change direction but still points at the same place, will it affect the way how it reflects the light ray or will it reflect normally

Comment: diffuse reflection always reflects in all directions, including the pinhole, so no changes will be observed in position.